# How can I customize the Ionic 2 app component to present content for both mobile and desktop?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, ionic2

Ionic 2 seems generally flexible enough to allow me to build both mobile and desktop apps, if only by simply dropping down to the underlying Angular 2 to create a separate set of pages for the desktop and trying to share as many components between them as possible. However, what I'd really like is to actually create one set of responsive pages for desktop AND mobile but customize navigation and page layout.

Assuming I can sort out navigational issues between the two, the main problem I'm having is simply how to apply a custom layout to the root component in app.html so it isn't just an empty container. I want it to have the typical fixed navbar at the top and some margin around the sides of a content area where pages are loaded into. Seems like this should be a pretty common use case, and I'm surprised I don't see more tips in the docs or anywhere on the web. What's the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering about this, it looks like the easiest way is to simply customize app.html with your own container structure for your desktop nav and page content a la:

```css
.center-outer{
  position: relative; 
 display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-container{
  background: $fb-blue;
  min-height: 102px;
}

.main-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
}

.center-inner{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#brand-logo{
  bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  max-height: 80px;
}

.platform-core{
// Critical overrides of Ionic styles for desktop environment layout within ion-grid
  ion-nav, .ion-page{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    contain: none;
  }

  .ion-page > ion-content{
    position: relative;
    contain: none;
  }

  .scroll-content{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    contain: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav container -->
<div class="center-outer header-container">
  <div class="center-inner">
    <nav id="top-nav">    
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img id="brand-logo" src="/assets/img/logo.jpg">
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let link of navLinks">       
          <a (click)="navToPage(link.page)">{{link.name}}</a>
        </li>     
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
 
<!-- Main container -->
<div class="center-outer main-container">
  <div class="center-inner">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <!--sidebar-->
        <ion-col width-20>
          <!--sidebar content...-->
        </ion-col>
        <!--page container-->
        <ion-col width-80>
          <div id="page">   
            <ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
          </div>
        </ion-col>    
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</div>
```